EF 6 code first with X# (or C#) does not create a database
I am struggling with EF 6 (for .NET 4.x), code first and SQLite.
I am using X# instead of C# but it does only affect the syntax.
The problem is that the SQLite database with the table is not created so SaveChanges() throws a "DbUpdateException" exception since the table does not exist (the db3 file will be created with 0 bytes):

Inner Exception 1:
UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
Inner Exception 2:
SQLiteException: SQL logic error
no such table: Blogs

The logging output only revealed that there is no table __MigrationHistory but this should not matter.
Here is the complete code:
USING System
USING System.Collections.Generic
USING System.Linq
USING System.Data.Entity

PUBLIC CLASS CustomIntializer INHERIT CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<BloggingContext>
    
    PROTECTED OVERRIDE METHOD Seed(context AS BloggingContext) AS VOID
        VAR Blogs := List<Blog>{} {;
            Blog {} {Name := "Blog 1"},;
            Blog {} {Name := "Blog 2"};
        }
        Blogs:ForEach({b => context:Blogs:Add(b)})
        context:SaveChanges()
    END METHOD
END CLASS

PUBLIC CLASS Blog
    PUBLIC PROPERTY BlogId AS INT AUTO
    PUBLIC PROPERTY Name AS STRING AUTO
    PUBLIC VIRTUAL PROPERTY Posts AS List<Post> AUTO
END CLASS

PUBLIC CLASS Post
    PUBLIC PROPERTY PostId AS INT AUTO
    PUBLIC PROPERTY Title AS STRING AUTO
    PUBLIC PROPERTY Content AS STRING AUTO
    PUBLIC PROPERTY BlogId AS INT AUTO
    PUBLIC PROPERTY Blog AS Blog AUTO
END CLASS

PUBLIC CLASS BloggingContext INHERIT DbContext
    PUBLIC PROPERTY Blogs AS DbSet<Blog> AUTO
    PUBLIC PROPERTY Posts AS DbSet<Post> AUTO
    
    CONSTRUCTOR()
        SUPER("DataContext")
        SELF:Database:Log := Console.WriteLine

END CLASS

FUNCTION Start() AS VOID STRICT
    Database.SetInitializer<BloggingContext>(CustomIntializer{})
    BEGIN USING VAR db := BloggingContext{}
        db:database:Initialize(force := TRUE)
        db:Blogs.Add(Blog{} {Name := "Blog 1"})
        db:SaveChanges()
    END USING
    Console.WriteLine("*** Database updated ***")
    Console.ReadLine()

And the app.config:
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" 
                 type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
                 requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory
            type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" 
                      type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
            <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)"
                 invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6"
                 description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)"
                 type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
            <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
            <add name="SQLite Data Provider"
                 invariant="System.Data.SQLite"
                 description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite"
                 type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DataContext"
             connectionString="Data Source=pemo.db3;Version=3"
             providerName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>

What am I missing, or does code-first with SQLite not work with EF 6?

There is no such thing as ".NET 4.x".

Did you create any initial migration and did you apply it to the database at any point?

Using a code first approach with SQLite, you need to call context.Database.Migrate() or context.Database.Create() to create the file.

With context.Database.Create() I'll get a "Database 'main' cannot be created because it already exists.'" error and the db3 file is created. And there is no Migrate() method with the Database property. Something is happening twice. II did not do an intial migration because thats not necessary, I was following a MS Learn tutorial for EF 6...
